# How to select files with less than n lines?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, merge, grep

Given a folder with n files with different numbers of lines :

```sh
$wc -l * | sort -n -r     # list and sort files by number of lines
> 99860 total
  50000 mr.txt
   4976 स.txt
   4462 प.txt
   3745 म.txt
   3545 क.txt
   3195 व.txt
   2201 न.txt
   2183 ब.txt
   2134 अ.txt
   1789 र.txt
   1666 द.txt
   1623 आ.txt
   1568 ग.txt
   1524 ज.txt
   1507 त.txt
   1376 श.txt
   1132 ल.txt
   1102 ह.txt
   1089 च.txt
   1076 उ.txt
   1025 भ.txt
    809 य.txt
    791 फ.txt
    766 ख.txt
    652 ट.txt
    645 घ.txt
    480 ए.txt
    456 इ.txt
    446 ध.txt
    420 ड.txt
    318 ठ.txt
    273 झ.txt
    182 थ.txt
    163 ओ.txt
    118 छ.txt
    115 ऑ.txt
     64 ऐ.txt
     55 ढ.txt
     44 औ.txt
     29 २.txt
     26 ई.txt
     20 ष.txt
     20 ऊ.txt
     20 १.txt
     14 ऋ.txt
      6 ऱ.txt
      4 ३.txt
      2 ९.txt
      2 ८.txt
      1 ॐ.txt
      1 ४.txt
```

**How to select files with less than 200 lines ?**

So I may feed those via `>> output.txt` to a final file.

Comment: Loop through the files. Get the length with `wc -l < "$filename`. If it's less than 200, append it to the output file: `cat "$filename" >> output.txt`

Comment: Which part of that is giving you trouble?

Comment: Note on "question focus", "close votes", and question improvement: Comments asking if I wanted non-default behaviors have been removed by the author. For clarity, my corresponding answer that I wanted alphabetic order (aka default order) have been removed. For clarity, the "merge" words, which is done by simple `>> output.txt`, have been removed. The question scope have been reduced at its most minimal issue : discriminate by line count, as requested.

Comment: Regardless of all that, you're still expected to show some initiative and try to solve the problem yourself, and then we'll help you fix it rather tha write it all for you.

Comment: When you see the clean format of the input and question you can be sure i searched and tried for one hour. I felt I was missing a tiny command i don't know of. Socowi's knowledge of awk and answer shows a one liner could do it. I'am thankful of for those who helped.

Comment: There's absolutely no evidence that you tried. What's so hard about `length=$(wc -l < "$filename")` and then `if [ $length -lt 200 ]`?

Comment: It's not enough to tell us that you tried, you have to show your attempted code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your filenames are free of whitespace and special symbols like `'"\`, use

```
wc -l * | awk '$1 < 200 {print $2}' | xargs cat >> merged.txt
```

Because `*` expands in sorted order concatenation is done alpabetical.

Comment: Works well and is easy to understand, thanks. For the fun, this will help the Marathi community to record thousands of words on Wikimedia [LinguaLibre](https://lingualibre.org), so Wiktionaries can provide audios for this language. Thank you : )

Answer (score 2):

An implementation in pure `bash`, without using any external command-line utilities. This will work for any filenames (including filenames containing newline characters), and also prevent the output file itself from being merged if it already exists:

```
#!/bin/bash

outfile='merged_output.txt'
cutoff=200
for file in *; do
    [[ $file = "$outfile" || ! -f $file ]] && continue
    mapfile -n "$cutoff" lines < "$file"
    (( ${#lines[@]} < cutoff )) && printf '%s' "${lines[@]}"
done >> "$outfile"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 { printf "%s", buf; buf="" }
    { buf = buf $0 ORS }
    FNR >= 200 { buf=""; nextfile }
' *
```

An awk that supports `nextfile` as a command will run faster than one that doesn't (which will just ignore it thinking it's an unset variable).

Comment: Thanks for this code, it will help the community and future readers : )